# cycle through array with ngFor and create a new row every x elements

Tags: angular

I want to display an array via *ngFor and start a new row every x elements.

How can I achieve that ? 
I'm trying something like this.

```
<tr>
<td *ngFor="let elements of myArray ; let index = index">
   // if !(index % x) create a new row
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do that in your component, and create an array of rows, each being an array of cells. Then use two nested ngFor in the template.

Comment: merci beaucoup !